# Add new server to HAProxy using dataplane api with Rate limiting in Golang

Tags: go, haproxy, rate-limiting

I am adding new backend server to Haproxy through my golang code. I can see there is a parameter called max connections while adding new server which can be used to limit no of connections. There is also a parameter called maxqueue which will queue the connections if max connection limit is reached. **But I cant find-out the option to specify the queue timeout. And I could not find from documentation what is default queue timeout time.**

Furthermore, How can I add rate limiting based on no of requests (sliding window) while adding new server to backend?
I can see there is an option of mentioning stick table however I could not find example of its implementation.

I am referring to below documentation.
https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/dataplaneapi/community/#post-/services/haproxy/configuration/servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A server have no "queue timeout". You can set the "queue timeout" via the backend configs

https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/dataplaneapi/community/#post-/services/haproxy/configuration/backends
https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/dataplaneapi/community/#put-/services/haproxy/configuration/backends/-name-

The defaults can be received via the defaults call.
https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/dataplaneapi/community/#get-/services/haproxy/configuration/defaults